# Wordpress connecting posts

Tags: plugins

I am creating a travel agency website. And i have

Hotels
Attractions
Tours
Cities

What i want to do is, when i enter a create city I want to see, hotels, attractions and tours which are in the specific city.

One way to achieve this is to achive this is to create a list of hotels, attractions and tours and hyperlink each element in that list. For each City post i create.

Furthermore if i enter a create a Tour i want to see, hotels, attractions, and the cities connected to that tour.

And so on.

My question is: can this process be automated. Or is there a ready solution for this?

Comment: This kind of data organization and navigation is pretty much what WordPress is built to do. There are likely many plugins and/or themes out there which would accomplish this out-of-the-box, however plugin recommendations are considered off-topic here. But if you'd like to implement it on your own, I can give you a run-down of how these systems are created using WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Posts 2 Posts. It's older, but it's rock solid and saves a ton of work. There's a github library and a plugin, depending on how you plan to implement it.

- https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/

Good luck.